# Making http://jquery-datatables.meteor.com/ ... run?

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, datatables

I'm fairly new to coding but I've managed to put together a basic website on an almost-default apache server using XAMPP, and after having spent days looking for a search results table that has the sorting features I need (search query box, search options, paging and multi-column sorting) I found http://jquery-datatables.meteor.com/

The example on that page is perfect, and I could take it apart bit by bit to figure out how it works and what each part of it does, if only I could get the github master package to run on my server...

Trying to access localhost/test/meteor-jquery-datatables-master/example/index.html I get a blank page, and on further inspection the index file simply contains this:

```
<head>
  <title>jQuery DataTables</title>
</head>

<template name="home">
  {{> reactiveQuery }}
</template>
```

I've never seen any code like what's in the template tags before, is that really supposed to run the entire example code? Is that JavaScript or what? Am I supposed to replace it with something else to make the example run? I read the readme file and was left none the wiser, I can barely figure out what it says! Something about coffee... and what seems to be linux commands, but I'm on windows.

Also, is it getting the search results from an SQL database or is that some other type of database? If not, any idea if it could be made to support MySQL or if not, what else do I have to use?

Probably an extremely nooby question, but any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You've stumbled upon a version of the popular DataTables plugin packaged up for the Meteor framework:

https://www.meteor.com/

Meteor is a fairly new JS framework with some cool features, but it's probably not ideal for learning your way around basic web coding, especially within a XAMPP setup. So I think the solution is easy - you just need the straightforward jQuery DataTable, without Meteor, which can be found here:

http://www.datatables.net/

It's a great plugin, I have used it a lot and I think you will get on with it well because it works well with XAMPP. Have a read of:

http://www.datatables.net/manual/installation

A very simple way to get started is:

- Create a PHP page that mostly builds a simple HTML page
- The HTML page includes the jQuery and DataTables JavaScript files
- Use a PHP loop to create an HTML table with a few hundred rows
- Create some JavaScript that calls the DataTables method on your table

and from there you should be able to work out how to make it more sophisticated.

Comment: Ahh... I thought Meteor was built from scratch, glad I was wrong, datatables.net has soooo much more documentation and explanations, very user-friendly really :) Thanks!

I've downloaded a copy of datatables along with their editor and put it on my server, and I can now have a working example of a premade table working. However, when I try to use the editor to create my own table with server-side processing, I get an error that says "No database selected" and I can't for the life of me figure out how to select a database... I could edit an example db if there was any hooked up by default